# Storing in CSV file - ruby separator

Tags: ruby, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I am trying to store the results from my scrapping exercice into a CSV file.

The current CSV file gives me the following output :

```
Name of Movie 1

Rating 1

Name of Movie 2 

Rating 2
```

I would like to get the following output :

```
Name of Movie 1 Rating 1 

Name of Movie 2 Rating 2
```

Here is my code, I guess it has to deal with the row / column separator :

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

array = []


for i in 1..10
  url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/meilleurs//?page=#{i}"
  html_file = open(url).read
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)


  html_doc.search('.img_side_content').each do |element|
    array << element.search('.no_underline').inner_text
    element.search('.note').each do |data|
      array << data.inner_text
    end
  end
end

puts array


csv_options = { row_sep: ',', force_quotes: true, quote_char: '"' }
filepath    = 'allocine.csv'

CSV.open(filepath, 'wb', csv_options) do |csv|
  array.each { |item| csv << [item] }
end
```

Comment: Hi @Pierrre, there are 2 types of rating: Presse and Spectateurs. What is your expected output? `Coco,4.1,4.6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are not pushing the elements correctly into your `array` variable. Basically, your array ends up looking like this:

```
['Movie 1 Title', 'Movie 1 rating', 'Movie 2 Title', 'Movie 2 rating', ...]
```

What you actually want is an array of arrays, like so:

```
[
  ['Movie 1 Title', 'Movie 1 rating'],
  ['Movie 2 Title', 'Movie 2 rating'],
  ...
]
```

And once your array is correctly set, you don't even need to specify a row separator in your CSV options.

The following should do the trick:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

array = []


10.times do |i|
  url = "http://www.allocine.fr/film/meilleurs//?page=#{i}"
  html_file = open(url).read
  html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html_file)


  html_doc.search('.img_side_content').each do |element|
    title = element.search('.no_underline').inner_text.strip
    notes = element.search('.note').map { |note| note.inner_text }
    array << [title, notes].flatten
  end
end

puts array

filepath    = 'allocine.csv'
csv_options = { force_quotes: true, quote_char: '"' }

CSV.open(filepath, 'w', csv_options) do |csv|
  array.each do |item|
    csv << item
  end
end
```

( I also took the liberty of changing your `for` loop to a `times`, which is more ruby-like ;) )